# Grant permissions on a stored procedure to tables in another schema

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, security, schema

I created a user in SQL Server 2012 database and revoked all permissions given by the `public` role.

Then I granted `EXECUTE` permission on a stored procedure.
The user can execute the procedure but cannot get the data it returns.

The procedure is in `schema1`, and the tables from which it selects are in `schema2`.

If I add the user to the `db_datareader` role it can read all data from all the tables in the database. I tried using `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` but it didn't work.

How can I grant only the access to the given procedure and nothing else?

Comment: `GRANT EXECUTE ON <procedure_name> TO <user_name>` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345484.aspx

Comment: I did exactly that and when the user tries to execute it, he recieves an error: SELECT permission denied on table... (there are multiple tables used by the sp and I don't want to explicitly grant permissions on all of them).

Comment: Are you perhaps using dynamic SQL in your stored procedure? Also, you may want to read up on ownership chaining, http://sqlsunday.com/2014/08/10/the-sql-server-security-model-part-4/

Comment: I don't use dynamic SQL in that procedure. The interesing things that I use are: UNIONS, parameters, subqueries, string functions, nondeterministic functions like GETDATE(), joining table that takes part in transactional replication.

Answer (score 7):

No, you do not want (or need) `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER`.

The problem is simply that your two schemas — `Schema1` wit the stored procedure, and `Schema2` with the tables — have different owners. If you execute the following query, you will see who owns which schemas:

```
SELECT *, USER_NAME([principal_id]) AS [UserName]
FROM   sys.schemas;
```

Ownership chaining, the default security mechanism, assumes DML and EXECUTE permissions on objects referenced by the object being accessed, *IF* the owner is the same. If no owner has been explicitly assigned to an object (default = `NULL`), then the "owner" is considered to be the owner of the schema in which the object exists.

So, technically your schemas *could* have the same owner and it's just that the tables have a different owner due to being given one explicitly (via `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`), but it's much more likely that the schemas have different owners.

Fortunately, this situation is easy to solve using [Module Signing](https://ModuleSigning.Info/).

The concept is to create a certificate in the database containing these schemas and objects, which will then be used to sign the stored procedure that exists in `Schema1` but selects from tables in `Schema2`.

A user is created from the certificate, and is then assigned whatever permission(s) are needed in order for the stored procedure to complete successfully.

No permissions are being granted to anyone that will be executing the stored procedure. The permissions are granted only to the certificate-based user. The connection between the stored procedure and the certificate-based user is (effectively) the public key of the certificate. And that public key is only loaded into the session's security context when a module that has been signed with that certificate is being executed. And that signature requires the certificate's password (in the `ADD SIGNATURE` statement), and is dropped if anyone changes even a single byte of the stored procedure (or the owner of it). Hence, very secure.

The following illustrates this concept:

**Main Setup**

```
CREATE SCHEMA [Schema1];
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [Schema2];
GO

CREATE USER [TestUser] WITHOUT LOGIN;

CREATE TABLE [Schema2].[Stuff]
(
  [StuffID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Stuff] PRIMARY KEY,
  [Stuff] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO [Schema2].[Stuff] ([Stuff]) VALUES (N'Success!!');

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema1].[GetStuff]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT [StuffID], [Stuff]
FROM   [Schema2].[Stuff];
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [Schema1].[GetStuff] TO [TestUser];
```

**Test Same Schema Owners**

```
EXECUTE AS USER = N'TestUser';
SELECT SUSER_NAME() AS [Login], USER_NAME() AS [User];

EXEC [Schema1].[GetStuff];
-- Success due to both Schemas having same owner


REVERT;
SELECT SUSER_NAME() AS [Login], USER_NAME() AS [User];
```

**Reproduce Current Situation**

```
SELECT *, USER_NAME([principal_id]) AS [UserName]
FROM   sys.schemas
WHERE  [name] IN (N'Schema1', N'Schema2');
/*
name       schema_id    principal_id    UserName
Schema1    5            1               dbo
Schema2    6            1               dbo
*/


ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[Schema2] TO [guest];


SELECT *, USER_NAME([principal_id]) AS [UserName]
FROM   sys.schemas
WHERE  [name] IN (N'Schema1', N'Schema2');
/*
name       schema_id    principal_id    UserName
Schema1    5            1               dbo
Schema2    6            2               guest
*/
```

**Test Current Situation (no extra permissions)**

```
EXECUTE AS USER = N'TestUser';
SELECT SUSER_NAME() AS [Login], USER_NAME() AS [User];

EXEC [Schema1].[GetStuff];
-- ERROR:
/*
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure Schema1.GetStuff, Line XXXXX [Batch Start Line YYYYY]
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Stuff', database '......', schema 'Schema2'.
*/


REVERT;
SELECT SUSER_NAME() AS [Login], USER_NAME() AS [User];
```

**Module Signing Setup**

```
-- Create Certificate and sign Stored Procedure with it:
CREATE CERTIFICATE [Permission$Schema2]
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'SomePassword'
    WITH SUBJECT = 'Used for selecting from objects in Schema2',
    EXPIRY_DATE = '2099-12-31';


ADD SIGNATURE
    TO [Schema1].[GetStuff]
    BY CERTIFICATE [Permission$Schema2]
    WITH PASSWORD = 'SomePassword';


-- Create Certificate-based User to hold permissions
CREATE USER [Permission$Schema2]
  FROM CERTIFICATE [Permission$Schema2];


-- Grant Certificate-based User ONLY the permissions needed
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::[Schema2] TO [Permission$Schema2];
```

**Test with Module Signing**

```
EXECUTE AS USER = N'TestUser';
SELECT SUSER_NAME() AS [Login], USER_NAME() AS [User];

EXEC [Schema1].[GetStuff];
-- 1    Success!!!


REVERT;
SELECT SUSER_NAME() AS [Login], USER_NAME() AS [User];
```

Comment: Every day, I think with me "damm I'm ready to be a senior. almost 5 years as a SQL DBA and a lot of experience..". Then I see these awesome answers...I'm not so ready I guess. Amazing explanation.

Comment: @RacerSQL Thanks for the compliment :-). And, there is so much to know that none of us will ever know it all. There are layers upon layers upon layers. I might now a lot about this stuff, but there are entire areas that I know very little, or even nothing, about. Just keep learning and trying, and you should do well :).

Comment: Sorry @SolomonRutzky, I have exactly the same owner on the schemas but I keep getting the error. I'm using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Ok I discovered the mystery. I am using SP with dynamic SQL and I repeated your setup creating a [Schema1].[GetStuffSTMT] procedure where I execute the same SQL but using execute [sys].[sp_executesql] SP and it throws error. Could you help me?

Comment: @jameswatt Hi James. I'm not understanding your exact setup. Are you getting the same error shown in the example above? Dynamic SQL also breaks ownership chaining, just like a different owner does. So whatever the dynamic SQL is attempting to do needs to be granted to the certificate-based User. Is the dynamic SQL doing DML statements or executing a stored procedure? If executing a stored proc, granting permissions to the certificate-based User will apply in terms of allowing the EXEC of the proc within dynamic SQL, but statements within _that_ proc are not granted anything via module signing.